# Need some advise with JS and CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I have a JS that makes some clouds to move around the screen. I want to limit the space that they use, for example to occupy the 300px from top.

I have trying to add "height:300px; top:0px;" in the DIV style but it didnt reach the desired result. Any ideas?

**Here is the complete script**

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2">

/*
Flying Butterfly script (By BGAudioDr@aol.com)
Modified slightly/ permission granted to Dynamic Drive to feature script in archive
For full source, visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com
*/

var Ymax=1;                                //MAX # OF PIXEL STEPS IN THE "X" DIRECTION
var Xmax=1;                                //MAX # OF PIXEL STEPS IN THE "Y" DIRECTION
var Tmax=100000;                        //MAX # OF MILLISECONDS BETWEEN PARAMETER CHANGES

//FLOATING IMAGE URLS FOR EACH IMAGE. ADD OR DELETE ENTRIES. KEEP ELEMENT NUMERICAL ORDER STARTING WITH "0" !!

var floatimages=new Array();
floatimages[0]='http://www.skydivemarianas.com/images/cloud.png';
floatimages[1]='http://www.skydivemarianas.com/images/cloud1.png';
floatimages[2]='http://www.skydivemarianas.com/images/cloud5.png';
floatimages[3]='http://www.skydivemarianas.com/images/cloud3.png';
floatimages[4]='http://www.skydivemarianas.com/images/cloud4.png';

//*********DO NOT EDIT BELOW***********
var NS4 = (navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape")>=0 && parseFloat(navigator.appVersion) >= 4 && parseFloat(navigator.appVersion) < 5)? true : false;
var IE4 = (document.all)? true : false;
var NS6 = (parseFloat(navigator.appVersion) >= 5 && navigator.appName.indexOf("Netscape")>=0 )? true: false;
var wind_w, wind_h, t='', IDs=new Array();
for(i=0; i<floatimages.length; i++){
t+=(NS4)?'<layer name="pic'+i+'" visibility="hide" width="10" height="10"><a href="javascript:hidebutterfly()">' : '<div id="pic'+i+'" style="position:absolute; z-index:10000000000; visibility:hidden;width:10px; height:10px"><a href="javascript:hidebutterfly()">';
t+='<img src="'+floatimages[i]+'" name="p'+i+'" border="0">';
t+=(NS4)? '</a></layer>':'</a></div>';
}
document.write(t);

function moveimage(num){
if(getidleft(num)+IDs[num].W+IDs[num].Xstep >= wind_w+getscrollx())IDs[num].Xdir=false;
if(getidleft(num)-IDs[num].Xstep<=getscrollx())IDs[num].Xdir=true;
if(getidtop(num)+IDs[num].H+IDs[num].Ystep >= wind_h+getscrolly())IDs[num].Ydir=false;
if(getidtop(num)-IDs[num].Ystep<=getscrolly())IDs[num].Ydir=true;
moveidby(num, (IDs[num].Xdir)? IDs[num].Xstep :  -IDs[num].Xstep , (IDs[num].Ydir)?  IDs[num].Ystep:  -IDs[num].Ystep);
}

function getnewprops(num){
IDs[num].Ydir=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)>0;
IDs[num].Xdir=Math.floor(Math.random()*2)>0;
IDs[num].Ystep=Math.ceil(Math.random()*Ymax);
IDs[num].Xstep=Math.ceil(Math.random()*Xmax)
setTimeout('getnewprops('+num+')', Math.floor(Math.random()*Tmax));
}

function getscrollx(){
if(NS4 || NS6)return window.pageXOffset;
if(IE4)return document.body.scrollLeft;
}

function getscrolly(){
if(NS4 || NS6)return window.pageYOffset;
if(IE4)return document.body.scrollTop;
}

function getid(name){
if(NS4)return document.layers[name];
if(IE4)return document.all[name];
if(NS6)return document.getElementById(name);
}

function moveidto(num,x,y){
if(NS4)IDs[num].moveTo(x,y);
if(IE4 || NS6){
IDs[num].style.left=x+'px';
IDs[num].style.top=y+'px';
}}

function getidleft(num){
if(NS4)return IDs[num].left;
if(IE4 || NS6)return parseInt(IDs[num].style.left);
}

function getidtop(num){
if(NS4)return IDs[num].top;
if(IE4 || NS6)return parseInt(IDs[num].style.top);
}

function moveidby(num,dx,dy){
if(NS4)IDs[num].moveBy(dx, dy);
if(IE4 || NS6){
IDs[num].style.left=(getidleft(num)+dx)+'px';
IDs[num].style.top=(getidtop(num)+dy)+'px';
}}

function getwindowwidth(){
if(NS4 || NS6)return window.innerWidth;
if(IE4)return document.body.clientWidth;
}

function getwindowheight(){
if(NS4 || NS6)return window.innerHeight;
if(IE4)return document.body.clientHeight;
}

function init(){
wind_w=getwindowwidth();
wind_h=getwindowheight();
for(i=0; i<floatimages.length; i++){
IDs[i]=getid('pic'+i);
if(NS4){
IDs[i].W=IDs[i].document.images["p"+i].width;
IDs[i].H=IDs[i].document.images["p"+i].height;
}
if(NS6 || IE4){
IDs[i].W=document.images["p"+i].width;
IDs[i].H=document.images["p"+i].height;
}
getnewprops(i);
moveidto(i , Math.floor(Math.random()*(wind_w-IDs[i].W)), Math.floor(Math.random()*(wind_h-IDs[i].H)));
if(NS4)IDs[i].visibility = "show";
if(IE4 || NS6)IDs[i].style.visibility = "visible";
startfly=setInterval('moveimage('+i+')',Math.floor(Math.random()*100)+100);
}}

function hidebutterfly(){
for(i=0; i<floatimages.length; i++){
if (IE4)
eval("document.all.pic"+i+".style.visibility='hidden'")
else if (NS6)
document.getElementById("pic"+i).style.visibility='hidden'
else if (NS4)
eval("document.pic"+i+".visibility='hide'")
clearInterval(startfly)
}
}

if (NS4||NS6||IE4){
window.onload=init;
window.onresize=function(){ wind_w=getwindowwidth(); wind_h=getwindowheight(); }
}

</script>
```

Comment: try `overflow: hidden`

Comment: surely if it's 300px from the top it should be `top:300px` rather than `height:300px`

Comment: I mean to occupy 300 px from the top

Comment: I think special coding for Netscape Navigator and IE 4 could easily be taken out of your code... :)  (which is A LOT!)

Comment: overflow: hidden;  hides it completely :)

Comment: No it shouldn't! Just the overflow... But really, what DIV are we talking about? The "butterfly" Divs are just 10x10 px. What other DIVs are there?

Comment: there is only one div indeed
<div id="pic'+i+'" style="position:absolute; z-index:10000000000; visibility:hidden;width:10px; height:10px"><a href="javascript:hidebutterfly()">

Comment: No it's not `for(i=0; i<floatimages.length; i++){` iterates so there are several. And they are 10x10 px. So where is the DIV you ask about?

Comment: I think the magic happens somewhere in the JS, but I am dummy with the JS :)

Comment: There is no real magic here, just a bunch of really outdated code. You could write this in 10 lines.

Comment: I am sure it can be done with 10 lines of code, but for someone that speaks JS.

Comment: Well, to solve your problem we need to know what you want to do. Since the only DIV's I can see is the 10x10px that contains the images, I think what you really want is to change the maximum distance from top of the WINDOW??? For that purpose you should look at the function `getwindowheight(){` that actually return the full window height.

Comment: what I want to do is to have the flying things not to go further than 300px from top... for the width they might go whenever they want.

Comment: Try changing the line `wind_h=getwindowheight();` to read `wind_h=300`;

Comment: tried that... if I put 300px it doesn't show at all, if i put just 300 it still goes further than 300px

Comment: The problem is that the images are too high. In fact they move from 0-300 if you set `wind_h=300` but the image height adds to the number. So if you want to limit it further either use smaller images or change it to ie `wind_h=100` and use max 200px high images.

Comment: just tried setting wind_h=300; with images 233x151 and they still fly everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cloud images are up to 329 px high, which mean that it will be hard to fit them under 300 px. But make the images a little smaller, ie max 200px high and then change the variable

```
 wind_h=100;
```

of the `init()` function.

The clouds will then extend to be max 100+200 px from top, with a vertical movement from 0-100.

Comment: just tried setting wind_h=100; with images 151px height and they still fly everywhere

Comment: No they dont. Here is an example with wind_h=100 and the same images: http://slcab.com/butterfly.html

Comment: Oh I did it on window.onload=init; not on the func... now it works correctly... thanks man